# How to set a property before saving to the database that is not in the form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 5 I can't seem to set a field without having the validation fail and return an error.

My model has:

```
  validates_presence_of :account_id, :guid, :name

  before_save :set_guid

  private
    def set_buid
      self.guid = SecureRandom.uuid
    end
```

When I am creating the model, **it fails with the validation error saying guid cannot be blank.**

```
def create
  @user = User.new(new_user_params)
  if @user.save
  ..
  ..

   private
     def new_user_params
       params.require(:user).permit(:name)
     end
```

## 2

Another issue I found is that merging fields doesn't work now either.  In rails 4 I do this:

```
if @user.update_attributes(new_user_params.merge(location_id: @location_id)
```

If I @user.inspect I can see that the location_id is not set.  This worked in rails 4?

How can I work around these 2 issues?  Is there a bug somewhere in my code?

Comment: About issue #2, are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Gerry nope, no errors.  It silently just doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least two options.

1. Set the value in the `create` action of your controller

Snippet:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(new_user_params)
  @user.guid = SecureRandom.uuid
  if @user.save
  ...
end
```

2. In your model, use before_validation and add a condition before assigning a value:

Snippet:

```
before_validation :set_guid

def set_guid
  return if self.persisted?
  self.guid = SecureRandom.uuid
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**1**

Use `before_validation` instead:

```
before_validation :set_guid
```

Check the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

**2**

[Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) works fine with rails ; your problem seems to be that user is not updating at all, check that all attributes in `new_user_params` (including `location_id`) ara valid entries for `User`.

If `update_attributes` fails, it will do so *silently*, that is, no exception will be raised. Check [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attributes) for more details.

Try using the *bang* method instead:

```
if @user.update_attributes!(new_user_params.merge(location_id: @location_id))
```

Comment: so this is new to rails 5?  is there a summary of all these little changes?

Comment: @Blankman It's also available in rails 4. As for the changes between releases, you can check them [here](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/releases/)

Comment: Be careful, it'll be called each time you update the record.

Comment: @yoones I don't want that!  Just on saving... so what do I do?

Comment: It is working but the before_save is not working. the guid does not get set it seems when I do a @user.inspect logging.

Comment: Can you test on _console_? What is the output?